# how to cut or break the loop of modulo and continue the loop in separate html table

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, modulo

badly need assistance how to break modulo in visible by 3 but i need it loop or continue the loop in separate html table, because in my mine.. it will continuing the loop like below

Sample_table

```
|     1    |
|     2    |
|     3    |
|     4    |
|     5    |
|     6    |
```

Current output

```
|     1    |     2   |     3    |
|     4    |     5   |     6    |
```

Desired Output

```
HTML table page 1
|     1    |     2   |     3    |

HTML table page 2
|     4    |     5   |     6    |
```

My current code

```php
//$resultz =  explode('xxx',$result['0']['tanning']);
//$i = 0;  
$i=0;
foreach($result as $results) {
    if ($i%3 == 0) {
        echo  "</tr><td><b>TITLE <br></b></td>";
        echo  "<td>".$results['data1']."</td>";
    } else {
        echo  "<td>".$results['data1']."</td>";
    }
    $i++;
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Thankss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be many solutions. 
May be so:

```
<?
// controller
/*$array = array(
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7
  // ...
);*/

$array =array(
    array('id'=>1,'name'=>'a'), 
    array('id'=>2,'name'=>'a'), 
    array('id'=>3,'name'=>'a'), 
    array('id'=>4,'name'=>'a'), 
    array('id'=>5,'name'=>'a'), 
    array('id'=>6,'name'=>'a'), 
    array('id'=>7,'name'=>'a')
); 

echo '$array <pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';

$column = 0;
$row = 0;
$maxColumn = 3; // max number of columns
$arrayNew = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val){
  $column++;

  $arrayNew[$row][$key] = $val;

  if ($column == $maxColumn){
    $column = 0;
    $row++;
  }
}

if( $column >= 1) { // add empty values ​​so that the table is beautiful (if necessary)
  for($i = 0; $i < ($maxColumn - $column); $i++){
    //$arrayNew[$row][] = '';
    $arrayNew[$row][] = array();
  }
}

// template
foreach ($arrayNew as $keyValueArray => $valueArray) { ?>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <?foreach ($valueArray as $key => $value) { ?>
        <td><?=$value['id']?></td>
      <?}?>
    </tr>
  </table>
<?}
```

Comment: thanks you and same output with my current work.. how about to my desire out put. please help me..

Comment: This example will split your array into several tables with one row and 3 columns. Did you want a different result?

Comment: i add table border and its work. but when i try to add my table field name, i got an error Array to string conversion

Comment: You can give an example part array and part php code where is the error

Comment: my quuery is something like this ```SELECT id, name FROM table "```  and its working.

Comment: or example this is may table ```$array =array(array('id'=>1,'name'=>'a'),
             array('id'=>2,'name'=>'a'),
             array('id'=>3,'name'=>'a'),
             array('id'=>4,'name'=>'a'),
             array('id'=>5,'name'=>'a'),
             array('id'=>6,'name'=>'a'),
             array('id'=>7,'name'=>'a')); ```

Comment: @luci I fixed the code in my answer, used your array. To understand the problem, run `var_dump` and see what data is in the variable and correct your code.

Comment: Thanks you. u save me.. Thanks you Thanks you